# What free, high-quality, mobile course apps are there for learning Icelandic?

Tags: resource-request, icelandic

As far as websites go, I was definitely able to find some, e.g. https://icelandiconline.com/, https://www.101languages.net/icelandic/, etc. However, I am having a hard time finding a decent, free (if possible), mobile app for Icelandic. The two resources I could find were a [Drops app](https://languagedrops.com/learn-icelandic/) and [a smattering of Memrise courses](https://www.memrise.com/courses/english/icelandic/), both of which are essentially glorified premade flashcards (sometimes Memrise can go further with listening exercises if sufficient audio has been provided, while Drops is either expensive ($10/mo; $70/yr) or severely limited (5min/day)).

I'm looking for an integrated course, if possible.

Criteria:

- Mobile app (Android, specifically, if possible)
- Listening, cloze, translation, and especially *pronunciation* ([as a native English speaker](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/399/85)) exercises (like Lingodeer or Duolingo)
- Free (or inexpensive)
- At least to A2~ish level

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of Anki decks for Icelandic: https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/icelandic

They are flashcard decks with no glorification. The deck https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/257529691 , 6500 sentences with audio, seems to have the same concept as a Danish deck I am using. From what I understand, it takes the sentences in Tatoeba, rates them by word frequency and gives the easiest first. It pronounces the sentence (computer-generated but passable for Danish, with some mispronounced sentences included) and when you are ready, reveals the sentence and an English translation.

The way I use the deck is that I am happy with knowing a sentence if I understand it, can write it correctly and can pronounce it in a passable way, up to my own judgment.

The deck is not a complete course by itself, but it stands on its own and is useful.

---

Clozemaster also seems to have content for Icelandic from English. It also uses Tatoeba sentences. I have not more than dabbled with Clozemaster, so I cannot comment on it. It might be quite challenging if you are a total beginner. If you use both the Anki deck and Clozemaster, the sentences might be familiar.

---

I'll also link to what I guess is the website of the Icelandic broadcasting company: http://www.ruv.is/ . Útvarp seems to contain the radio channels. Those are likely to be useful once you are at the level where you can understand speech. There is also written news and videos.

Comment: I have used Clozemaster for different languages before (and totally forgot to search in it for this question!). You're correct that it is difficult for total beginners, but it will 100% fulfill my quest for cloze cards!